# Buggy VTOL controls in Crysis?

Tags: technical-issues, crysis

I’m playing through Crysis for the first time, and the VTOL controls seem buggy, to say the least. I am currently in a quiet spot, no enemies, so I can experiment with them under no pressure.

It seems that at least 75% of the time, pressing the control keys just has no effect whatsoever. I’m hovering completely still, at a fixed altitude, press Space - it goes up. Press W - it goes forward. 5 seconds later the controls shut down: I’m stationary, pressing Space does nothing, pressing W does nothing either.

What gives? Is this a known bug? Is there a fix/work-around for this?

(Searching for this finds a couple of frustrated gamers, each told that they are just stupid or can’t figure out the controls by people who obviously don’t experience the bug.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I felt the control behaving in a very similar manner when I played Crysis. At some point in the single player campaign towards the end, the afterburner didn't seem to do any favor and the controls barely responded. But that only seemed to be the desired effect from the game developers' standpont, a kind of overwhelming effect created by the growing sphere and the sudden climatic changes created by the alien's insurrection. Even some of the game guides said you will have to go through a frustrating loop of dying and respawning till you get lucky. I lost track of the count of times I respawned till I got lucky enough to find a better direction/path. I guess it's the same case for you!

Comment: If this is the case then they’ve done a terrible job; they could have made the HUD malfunction during these occurrences or something like that to indicate that it’s not a bug... As for the dying, I have to admit I played on god mode because it was more fun that way and I have too little time...

Comment: well... they all have their shortcomings i guess.. you could still make your way through after a few attempts though.. but playing on god mode sometimes kills the experience and interest.. but that's just my opinion.. once you get off the island the game's barely another 30 minutes and that's quite a visual treat

Comment: Odd, I never experienced this during the campaign...though, I was eager to get out of there as fast as I could.

Answer (score 1):

I found there's an invisible wall that keeps you from leaving that valley if you're flying too high.  If you fly just above the tree level, you will be allowed to leave the area.